# Regex for one column that has numbers and letters but not one or the other

Tags: sql-server, regex

I am attempting to search a column that contains alphanumeric ids in it but want to write a query that returns records with letters and numbers but not one or the other.

```
i.e Acceptable: jjk44kndkfndFF

i.e Not acceptable: 223232323232   or  aajnfdskDFdd
```

So far I have:

```
where  PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%',columnInQuestion)
```

This returns all alphanumeric records. Any direction appreciated

Comment: %^([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)[0-9a-zA-Z]*$% This seems to work for what i want but not in sql server

Comment: Have you considered CLR functions? Checkout https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/ to see if this gives you a means of achieving what you are looking for. I've not tried it but using http://www.sqlsharp.com/ may also provide you an answer with less manual effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need three predicates in the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE (columnInQuestion NOT LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%') AND 
      (PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z]%', columnInQuestion) <> 0) AND
      (PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', columnInQuestion) <> 0)
```

- First predicate `(columnInQuestion NOT LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%')` is true if  `columnInQuestion` contains *only* alphanumeric characters
- Second predicate `(PATINDEX('%[a-zA-Z]%', columnInQuestion) <> 0)` is true if there is at least one alphabetic character in `columnInQuestion`
- Third predicate `(PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', columnInQuestion) <> 0)` is true if there is at least one numeric character in `columnInQuestion`

Comment: Thanks Giorgos, That really helped me out

Comment: What expression I must use when need text like Alphabet+Number only like `RHX9707` but not `0CA100` and not `KH4X104` and not `HXGGRR`

Only letter then number. required like `RHX9707`

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with just one regexp:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]*([a-zA-Z][0-9]|[0-9][a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

It starts and ends with 0-x legal chars.

And somewhere there is a switch from a letter to a digit or from a digit to a letter.

Comment: `*` doesn't work in SQL server as the "multiple times" operator